# SELECT custom fields and all fields when LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I'm selecting data from 2 tables.

```
$sql = "SELECT tb1.id, tb2.name FROM tblA tbl1 LEFT JOIN tblB tbl2 ON tb1.id = tbl2.studentID ORDER BY tbl1.id DESC LIMIT 20";
$statement = $con_db->prepare($sql);
```

My question is now can I SELECT custom fields from tb1 and all fields in tb2? e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT tb1.id, tb1.subject, tb2.(*) FROM ....";
```

Comment: Yes. Have you tried? I use the syntax `tb2.*`

Comment: @mseifert. Thanks. No I have no clue even if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the code like below

```
$sql = "SELECT tb1.id, tb1.subject, tb2.* FROM tblA tbl1 LEFT JOIN tblB tbl2 ON tb1.id = tbl2.studentID ORDER BY tbl1.id DESC LIMIT 20";
```